# What if there is an error message that adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, java

When `brew cleanup` shows the following error message:

```
Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:
  homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
  adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

How can I resolve this error without reinstalling Homebrew?

FYI some relevant references:

- https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/6112 - looks like an issue to be resolved on Homebrew itself
- https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/issues/106 - original bug report
- https://improve-future.com/en/how-to-solve-the-homebrew-error-cask-adoptopenjdk8-exists-in-multiple-taps.html - solved by reinstalling Homebrew

Answer (score 19):

Here is a quick solution which assumes that Homebrew is up-to-date and there is no need to use any other packages from the `adoptopenjdk/openjdk` tap:

Check the state of `adoptopenjdk/openjdk` tap and `adoptopenjdk8` package:

- `brew tap` - lists which taps are currently enabled
- `brew search adoptopenjdk8` - shows which `adoptopenjdk8` casks are available from the enabled taps and which `adoptopenjdk8` casks are currently installed

Now assuming that the `adoptopenjdk/openjdk` tap is listed as enabled, remove the `adoptopenjdk/openjdk` tap as follows:

```
brew untap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
```

Then check what `adoptopenjdk8` casks are currently installed. This should show exactly one `adoptopenjdk8` cask installed.

At this point, `brew cleanup` should work correctly.

My explanation: it *appears* to me that they added `adoptopenjdk8` to the built-in Homebrew caskroom.

Note that it *should* be OK to do `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk` afterwards, if needed. (This has not caused any issues for me so far.)

Comment: Works great, OP if this worked for you please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

I resoved this problem as follows commands:

```
brew uninstall adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quick solution: remove cask file

```
sudo rm /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/Casks/adoptopenjdk8.rb
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Posts should be more than just 1 line.  See [answer] for tips on providing answers here.  You can [edit] your post to add info such as why you're proposing this solution or why it's different than the one already provided.

Comment: This worked for me - after other suggestions including highly voted one above did not. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with

```
$ brew uninstall adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
==> Uninstalling Cask adoptopenjdk8
==> Uninstalling packages; your password may be necessary:
net.adoptopenjdk.8.jdk
Password:
==> Purging files for version 8,292:b10 of Cask adoptopenjdk8
```